# Form based authentication login servlet code

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, jboss, jboss7.x

I was following [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/bncby/index.html) to create form-based authentication in for my jboss java EE 6 application.

However it has no code for the login servlet. After searching other resources I found that the login servlet code is not mentioned anywhere.

Where can I find the code for the login servlet? Maybe its very basic, but I am new to Java and I can't write it myself.

Comment: if you wish to use a very basic authentication using a DB you can try this:
http://www.javatpoint.com/example-of-login-form-in-servlet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial doesn't have servlet code because the security is provided by the container itself and container security is configured using the deployment descriptor.

You may read [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072850/java-security/j2ee-security--container-versus-custom.html) for further information and decide whether you use the container security or a custom implementation.

Answer (score 1):

At Stormpath, we have a ready-to-use login Servlet that you could use. The only caveat is that it requires Servlet 3.0 or later and it is coupled to our own [User Management service](https://stormpath.com/).

Our Login Servlet will automate all user registration, login, authentication and authorization workloads.

Take a look at this one page long quickstart: https://docs.stormpath.com/java/servlet-plugin/quickstart.html. It will describe the few steps that you need to carry out to integrate it into your app.

BTW, the Servlet Plugin is completely open source; the code is [here](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java/tree/master/extensions/servlet) in case you want to take a look at it.